# what's wrong with my jquery multiple selector?

Tags: jquery, selector

I want to select a dynamical element which is num1 first, then find its ul (id=myUl)

```
<div id="num1"></div> // dynamic
<ul id="myUl">
```

so I found its id (let's set it to currentNum) and had been converted into the integer, but my expression did not work :

```
$("div#num" + currentNum + "myUl")
```

I think the semicolon is wrong placed

Comment: why not just `$('#myUl')` That is not dynamic right.. and ids are supposet to be unique..

Comment: _"I think the semicolon is wrong placed"_ What semicolon?

Comment: You should change `myUl` to be a class rather than an ID, since it looks like it won't be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way. You can use next(). for your selector to work second div must be a descendant of your random number div.(This statement is valid before your question update). WIth your updated question the selector is completely incorrect.

```
 $("#num" + currentNum).next('#myUl');
```

But since it is id you can just do

```
$('#myUl');
```

Also avoid prefixing the tagname on id. i.e `div#num` which is not required and also which makes it slower than just the id selector.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:  `$("div#num" + currentNum + "myUl")` to this:

```
$("div#num" + currentNum).next("ul#myUl")
```

You should only have 1 unique id on a page at a time.  So just do id selector instead as PSL suggested.